# How can I compute the mean of values selected from a vector A from an indexing vector B?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I have a vector of values, for example:

```
import torch
v = torch.rand(6)
```

```
tensor([0.0811, 0.9658, 0.1901, 0.0872, 0.8895, 0.9647])
```

and an `index` to select values from `v`:

```
index = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2])
```

I want to produce a vector `mean` which would compute the mean values of `v` grouped by indexes from `index`.

In this example:

```
mean = torch.tensor([(0.0811 + 0.1901 + 0.8895) / 3, 0.9658, (0.0872 + 0.9647) / 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

```
tensor([0.3869, 0.9658, 0.5260, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000])
```

Answer (score 2):

**One possible solution using a combination of `torch.bincount` and Tensor.index_add():**

```
v = torch.tensor([0.0811, 0.9658, 0.1901, 0.0872, 0.8895, 0.9647])
index = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2])
```

bincount() gets the total for each index use in `index`:

```
bincount = torch.bincount(index, minlength=6)
# --> tensor([3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

index_add() adds from `v` in the order given by `index`:

```
numerator = torch.zeros(6)
numerator = numerator.index_add(0, index, v)
# --> tensor([1.1607, 0.9658, 1.0520, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000])
```

Replace zeros with 1.0 in bincount to prevent division by 0 
and convert from int to float:

```
div = bincount.float()
div[bincount == 0] = 1.0
# --> tensor([3., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.])

mean = num/div
# --> tensor([0.3869, 0.9658, 0.5260, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000])
```